# Angular 2 parser, compiler and resulting artifact

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I m learning angular 2 internals and I m having some questions related on the compiler.

**What I think I've got in mind**

We have to pass to different state when building an angular application like:

*Source code (TS we write) => parsing (AST) => compiling (Inlining elements & views based on AST) => Artifact for browser*

Materialized by these components :

- Views are a "list" (or at least multiple) of dom nodes, angular directives, some expressions, CompileElements etc... representing templates instances
- The CompileElement contains information related on the element based on dynamic context (proper for compilation)

**My question is the following one**

The fact that Views are Inlining elements instead of lists / Maps reduces complexity and creates VM Friendly code, I think I've got that point.

But, does it mean, that during compilation, angular 2 creates, for each Views, a *unique representation of its class* ?

What I mean there, is : does angular 2 *recreates, for each templates* a new class definition that would have its own inlined elements, with its own change mecanism ? With every representation different from another one ?

Like :

- ATemplate with prop a, b, c
- BTemplate with prop d, e, f

Will have two different class representations (even at a property level)à ?

I m probably missing a point right there, I need some help to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding Angular2 Compiler with **Tobias Bosch**.

Following link  might help you, I guess.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW9cJsvcsGo

Comment: I've seen this awesome video,  but I m still having the previous incertitude points. Thanks for your answer